# jquery jwysiwyg extending default controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwysiwyg

I am trying to override a default control in jwysiwyg. Whenever I do this and click on the control I am overriding, I get this error:  `$.data(this, "wysiwyg") is undefined`.  Here is the code I am using.

```
    $('.wysiwyg').wysiwyg({
    css: "css/wysiwyg.css",
    controls: {
      bold: {
        visible: true,
        exec: function() { 
            $('.wysiwyg').wysiwyg('insertImage', 'path/to/image.jpg');  
        },

      }
    }
  });
```

Also, I can change the control I am overriding from bold, to any other default control (strikeThrough, ...) and I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Because function defined in exec operates not in your initial document, but in iframe document created by jwysiwig. 
And in iframe document there is no such thing as jwysiwig container.